# Declare method unavailable since a specific version of iOS in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, availability

I wish to achieve something like that:

```
@unavailable(iOS 11.0, *)
func oldWay() { 
    ...
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func newWay() { 
    ...
}
```

I've tried things like `@available(iOS 11.0, unavailable, *)` but it does not compile.

My problem is that I'm conforming to an Objective-C protocol with optional methods. Some of them are only available since iOS 11, my app is available since iOS 10 and I don't want to have both methods implemented for a given platform.

For instance if I do this:

```
func oldWay() { 
    ...
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func newWay() { 
    ...
}
```

Both methods are implemented on all platforms since iOS 11... That's not what I'm looking for.

So if anyone has an idea...

Comment: Would you be better off inheriting from the protocol with your own protocol version written in ObjC? If you did that, seems like you could go macro-crazy, and probably get it to do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `deprecated:` argument (and potentially `message:` as well), because that seems to be what's happening here:

```
@available(iOS, deprecated: 11.0, message: "Please use 'newWay'")
func oldWay() {

}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func newWay() {

}
```

This will produce a warning if you try to use the old way. If you want an error instead, replace `deprecated` with `obsoleted`.

Comment: I don't want deprecation, but unavailablilty. A deprecated method is still compiled and implemented. Moreover the Objective-C code when testing if a method is implemented has no information on deprecation.

Comment: @Zaphod Looking at the generated headers, methods marked with `obsoleted` look like this `- (void)foo SWIFT_AVAILABILITY(ios,obsoleted=11.0);`. I don't know much Objective-C, but can't you check for that? To me, this sounds like you need to rewrite the code that "tests if a method is implemented", rather than your Swift code.

Comment: `obsoleted` compiles for me, thanks @Sweeper, learned something here.

I suggested inheriting the protocol in ObjC above, might be easier.

Comment: The Obj-C protocol is not mine, unfortunately. I think the outcome is still different, because when it's not available, you simply does not have the implementation, do you? If you write `@available(iOS, unavailable)` you won't have it at all in the headers. Besides, I just want the Objective-C method `respondsToSelector` to return false for this method.

Comment: @Zaphod It _will_ still be in the headers even if you write `@available(iOS, unavailable)`. It will appear as `- (void)foo SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;`. If you just want `respondsToSelector` to return false, I guess you could always manually override it... Not a "clean" solution per se, but it should work...

Comment: Thank you for this information. I'll contact the framework team.